# How to estimate homography using RANSAC on Lucas-Kanade matching results?

Tags: computer-vision, matlab-cvst, homography, opticalflow, ransac

In image matching, with Matlab, I found a vector of correspondence of two images using Lucas-Kanade algorithm and now I have to estimate the homography matrix using RANSAC. Any simple way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In Lucas Kanade algorithm flow vectors are estimated by searching for specific points of previous image in next image. If you are using `opencv` you have function `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`. Which gives out coordinates of tracked points in destination image. You can check [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html).

Having points in current image, and corresponding points in previous image, there are readily available functions to estimate Homography matrix.[here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=findhomography#findhomography)

```
findHomography(srcPoints, dstPoints, method, ransacReprojThreshold);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `estimateGeometricTransform` function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.